# Navigation title and bar button items disappears

Tags: ios

I had the problem in my project where the titles and Navigation Bar button items were missing from the navigation bars in Xcode 9 and iOS 11. I'm not using the navigation controller just using the navigation bars in the view controllers, and all these viewcontroller have the relationship with the tabViewController. When I get into the app main view of the tabViewController shows the title and navigation bar button items but when I switch the tabs the title and navigation bar items disappear.And I'm using storyboards for this.

[image: This Is navigation bar 1]

[image: This Is navigation bar 2]

[image: I can see the navigation bar 2 on simulator]

[image: Title and bar button of navigation bar 1 disappears on simulator]

Comment: Write some relevant code

Comment: I'm using story boards only.